# LTC3115 component selection for schematic

Tags: switching-regulator, buck-boost

For my project I am using the LTC3115 Buck-Boost converter ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3115-1.pdf)) that should provide an output voltage of 8 V and 700 mA with a switching frequency of 2 MHz. The input voltage range is 3.2 V to 4.2 V. The schematic, components values and application details are provided only for 5 V, 12 V and 24 V output voltages. What are the component values that are required to obtain the output voltage and current that I have said above?

Comment: What does page 29 say about it?

Comment: I've seen the  output voltage setting using the resistor divider feedback and didn't had any issues with that. But the thing I can't understand is the components selection for the loop compensation that is mentioned in page 26, 27, 28. They've provided a bode plot for some pre-defined values. So, if I want to use that loop compensation technique in my system for the input and output values that I've mentioned in my question, what will be the resistor and capacitor values that I have to connect to the VC pin? Or is that loop compensation optional?

Comment: Ah! The top resistor of the divider has an influence on the loop compensation. If I where you I would enter all variables and formulas into excel or similar and try to adjust accordingly to match the datasheet recommendations, but for 8 V in your case.

Comment: LT PowerCAD is your friend in cases like this. https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/ltpowercad.html